# Display object properties of an array based on id using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javaScript and developing a client side shopping cart using javaScript. I have displayed product details from an array in separate DIVS and looped anchor tag also. What i would do is, when an anchor tag is clicked(add to cart), only that particular product should be displayed in a separate div. How can I pass the product id(id1) to href when each buttons are clicked? Can anyone give any idea? I really appreciate your efforts. Here is my code sample.

```js
var cakeDetails = [
  {
    id1: "1",
    cakeimage: "images/cup3.png",
    cakename: "White chocolate cheese cake",
    price: "£25"
  }, 
  {
    id1: "2",
    cakeimage: "images/cup2.png",
    cakename: "Angel cup cake",
    price: "£1"
  }, 
  {
    id1: "3",
    cakeimage: "images/cup5.png",
    cakename: "Lemon cup cake",
    price: "£1"
  }
];

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
 
  var container = "<div class='productMainContainer'>";

  for (var i = 0; i < cakeDetails.length; i++) {
    container+="<div class='productContainers'>";
    container+="<div class='productImgContainer'>";
    container+='<img src="'+cakeDetails[i].cakeimage+'">'; 
    container+="</div>";
    container+="<div class='productName'>"+cakeDetails[i].cakename+"</div>";
    container+="<div class='productPrice'>"+cakeDetails[i].price+"</div>"; 
    container+="<a href=''>"+"Add to cart"+"</a>";
    container+="</div>";
  }

  container+="</div>";

  document.getElementById("productDisplay").innerHTML = container;
});
```

```html
<div class="productOuterContainer" id="productDisplay"></div>
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! you've provided some useful details, but your question is still missing key information; please see SO's [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ways to improve your question and make it more practical for others to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button with an `onclick` attribute that calls a function to make the product appear in a separate div. The button should have an attribute containing the ID of a product so that when the `onclick` event handler is called, you can retrieve the attribute containing the ID from the element passed as an argument to the function that's called by the `onclick`.

```
<button data-id="${detail.id1}" onclick="addToCart(this)">
  ${'Add to cart'}
</button>`
```

We interpolate the ID of the cake detail into the HTML we generate in the following functions.

```js
var cakeDetails = [
  {
    id1: "1",
    cakeimage: "images/cup3.png",
    cakename: "White chocolate cheese cake",
    price: "£25"
  }, 
  {
    id1: "2",
    cakeimage: "images/cup2.png",
    cakename: "Angel cup cake",
    price: "£1"
  }, 
  {
    id1: "3",
    cakeimage: "images/cup5.png",
    cakename: "Lemon cup cake",
    price: "£1"
  }
];

function getCakeDetailForId(id) {
  for(const detail of cakeDetails) {
    if (detail.id1 === id) return detail;
  }
}

function addToCart(anchor) {
  const cakeId = anchor.getAttribute('data-id');
  const cakeDetail = getCakeDetailForId(cakeId);
  if (cakeDetail) { 
    const container = productContainerFromCakeDetail(cakeDetail);
    document.getElementById("cartDisplay").innerHTML = container;
  } else {
    console.log(`couldn't find cake detail for #${cakeId}`);
  }
}

function productContainerFromCakeDetail(detail, addToCart = false) {
  return `
    <div class="productContainers">
      <div class="productImgContainer">
        <img src="${detail.cakeimage}">
      </div>
      <div class="productName">${detail.cakename}</div>
      <div class="productPrice">${detail.price}</div>
      ${addToCart ? `<button data-id="${detail.id1}" onclick="addToCart(this)">
        ${'Add to cart'}
      </button>` : ''}
    </div>
  `;
}

function productMainContainer() {
  return `
    <div class='productMainContainer'>
      ${cakeDetails.map(detail => productContainerFromCakeDetail(detail, addToCart)).join('\n')}
    </div>
  `;
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  document.getElementById("productDisplay").innerHTML = productMainContainer();
});
```

```html
<aside style="float:right">
  <h2>Last Product Added</h2>
  <div id="cartDisplay">
    <!-- Last product added to cart -->
  </div>
</aside>
<h2>All Products</h2>
<div class="productOuterContainer" id="productDisplay">
  <!-- List of products -->
</div>
```